# table borders vertical and horizontal not meeting

Tags: html, css

I have a simple table and im only trying to get borders around some of the cells.

```css
.comments .b {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #919295;
}
.comments .t {
  border-top: 1px solid #919295;
}
.comments .l {
  border-left: 1px solid #919295;
}
.comments .r {
  border-right: 1px solid #919295;
}
```

```html
<table align='center' width='100%' class='comments'>
  <tr>    
    <th width='15%' class='r b'>val</th>
    <th width='45%'>ba</th>
    <th width='40%'>"sadf</th>
  </tr>   
  <tr>    
    <th width='15%' class='r b'>"dsf</th>
    <th rowspan='2' colspan='2'>"sdf</th>
  </tr>
  <tr height='60px'><th colspan='3'>&nbsp;</th></tr>
  <tr height='35px'><th>&nbsp;</th><th colspan='2'>&nbsp;</th></tr>
</table>
```

The result is:

[image]

How can i remove the spaces indicated by the arrows?

I have tried `border-spacing: 0px;`

Comment: Please post a JSfiddle your code is not working in my codepen

Comment: Are you intentionally using only `th` (i.e. "table header") elements and no `td`s?

Comment: added fiddle.  not intentional, just got coding and didnt realize, changing to td doesn't change anything.

Comment: add cell-spacing and cell-padding to 0 too for the table

Comment: `border-spacing: 0` works for me. How did you try it?

Comment: hmm, some combination of border-spacing and border-collapse fixed it.  going to retake my steps and post what i did.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add

```
table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
}
```